# How to connect to internet using Reliance NetConnect data card?

Tags: internet, usb-modem

I have a Reliance NetConnect Data card. I have plugged the datacard to my PC but it doesn't autorun or asks for installation as it does on Windows. Without it being installed I cannot connect to the internet. I am using Ubuntu 12.10 32-bit in case it matters.

How to connect to internet using Reliance NetConnect data card?

Comment: go to to this link
<br/><br/><http://askubuntu.com/questions/626207/unable-to-connect-to-the-internet-on-a-ubuntu-14-0-4-laptop-using-ztereliance-c/626681#626681>

Comment: No need to install any applications, This one will help!

http://askubuntu.com/a/509264/142825

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to install two software packages to make the internet connectivity work consistently without breaking. They are wvdial and gnome-ppp (The front-end tool to configure wvdial).

1. Install wvdial package

   Open terminal,(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type the following command

   ```
    sudo apt-get install wvdial
   ```
2. Install gnome-ppp

   ```
    sudo apt-get install gnome-ppp
   ```
3. Open gnome-ppp from the terminal.

   ```
    sudo gnome-ppp
   ```
4. You have to enter your reliance 10-digit mobile number in the Username & your password. Select #777 if you are a Reliance Netconnect Broadband+ user. Then press the Setup button below.
5. In the Setup window below, click the “Detect” button to identify the device ID of the USB port in which you have inserted your USB modem. The tool would automatically detect the Device, Type  and Speed of your USB modem. Once it has deteced, please the “Close” button below.

Once this is done click on Connect!!!

Comment: This process fails with the 13.04 distribution.

Comment: @Indian I'll try it out for 13.04 and let you know!

Comment: i have tested this on 13.04 and it works.

Comment: Thanks alot @Mukund It works like charm.  I am using Ubuntu 14.04 ( in India).

Comment: Perfect ! +1 Worked for 14.04 Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can install the Reliance Netconnect software in Ubuntu. Just follow these steps and you will get connected:

1. Connect your dongle and open the drive which you can see in your Launcher. You can see various files including Windows installer etc.
2. Copy the *Linux* folder and *install_linux* file from your dongle. These files will be stored in your dongle.
3. Create a folder in Desktop. For easy access, name it as *Reliance-Linux*. Copy the above two files and paste it into *Reliance-Linux* folder in Desktop.
4. Open Gedit and paste the following code:

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash


   CURRENT_PATH=`echo $0|sed 's/autorun.sh//'`

   "${CURRENT_PATH}"/install_linux
   ```

   save the file as `autorun.sh` in *Reliance-Linux* folder which you had created.
5. Now open the terminal and type the command `sudo -i`. Enter your password if prompted.
6. Then you have to `cd` to Desktop and install the Reliance Netconnect software as

   ```
   cd ~/Desktop/Reliance-Linux
   chmod +x ./install_linux
   ./install_linux
   ```
7. After installation is complete Search for Reliance Netconnect in Dash.
8. Keep surfing!!

[Note: step 4 is optional if `autorun.sh` is already present in Linux folder of your dongle]

For dongles like Airtel 3G & MTS, the method is the same.