# how to install "Reliance 3G" USB Dongle in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, modem, 3g

Hello Ubuntu Community,

Please give instructions to use Reliance 3G USB Dongle in Ubuntu 14.04.

I've tried various methods on web / Ubuntu forum / Ask Ubuntu, but they are not working for me. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Dongle name/number ??

Comment: ZTE, HSUPA USB Stick
Model : MF 190

Comment: @Volker Siegel

Those were few commands something related to wvdial and some other stuff.

But I got it now.

Thanks for your Quick attempt. :)

Its a 1st week since Ubuntu Installation, facing trouble to do some basic stuff..... but that's fine...I'm liking it now due to askUbuntu.com / people like you who are ready to help always. Thanks again.

Comment: I see you answered it, great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the below information from another Question which was for Airtel (Different Provider), but its working for Reliance as well... I guess should work for all.

### To connect without username and password

Network Connection -> Mobile Broadband -> Add

Now there are 5 simple steps; select the natural options:

1. Select appropriate mobile device : ZTE
2. Choose country provider/region : India
3. Choose your provider : Reliance
4. Choose your Billing Plan : NetConnect (Accordingly)
5. Confirm Mobile broadband settings (confirm)

Since in my case it was without password, I din't have to do any extra settings related to ip address or any setting in the final dialog.

### To connect with username and password

If connection failed you need credentials to connect. To do that,

1. Open network connections and go to *Edit connections...*
2. Under the **Mobile Broadband** select your connection name and click *Edit*.
3. From the editing window you can give *Username* and *Password*. (Combo will be *net* for Reliance).
4. Then *Save* and try connecting again.

Comment: I tried it, but it says, I can accept it after ONLY after 2 days

Comment: You may accept it now.